# How to fix "Experimental values on scalar is now forbidden"

Tags: perl

In Perl 5.26.1 I get:

> Experimental values on scalar is now forbidden at /funcx.pm line 110.

Where line 110 is the foreach in

```
sub checkSsh {
    foreach my $slave (values $::c{slaves}) {
      ...
    }
}
```

`$c` contains

```
$VAR1 = {
          'slaves' => {
                        '48' => '10.10.10.48'
                      },
        };
```

where

```
our %c = %{YAML::Syck::LoadFile($config)};
```

**Question**

What is actually the problem? And how should it be fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl is complaining that you are calling the [`values`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) builtin on a SCALAR, in this case a HASHREF:

Properly de-referencing your `slaves` key allows `values` to work as expected:

```
foreach my $slave ( values %{ $c{slaves} } ) {
  ...
}
```

As to the specific warning you receive, they address that directly in the perldoc page:

> Starting with Perl 5.14, an experimental feature allowed values to
>   take a scalar expression. This experiment has been deemed
>   unsuccessful, and was removed as of Perl 5.24.
>
> To avoid confusing would-be users of your code who are running earlier
>   versions of Perl with mysterious syntax errors, put this sort of thing
>   at the top of your file to signal that your code will work only on
>   Perls of a recent vintage:
>
> ```
> use 5.012;  # so keys/values/each work on arrays
> ```

Comment: I see I have this issue multiple places also with `keys` in `foreach my $id (keys $::c{slaves}) {`.

Comment: Right, it is the same issue. `keys` and `values` are meant to be called on a hash. You are calling it on a hash *reference*, which is a SCALAR

Comment: Just to further confuse the issue, the questioner could also use the postfix dereferencing form `values $x->%*` as in [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Postfix-Dereference-Syntax) since they're using Perl >= 5.20.